# Shouldn't the last p property override all the p properties above it ?

Tags: html, css

```
<style>
#content p {color: yellow;}
p {color: purple;}
p {color: green;}
</style>
```

when I ran the code, all the p became yellow instead of green ( which was what I expected. )

html code here :

```
<div id="content">
<p>Duis autem vel eum </p>
<p>Duis autem vel eum </p>
<p>Duis autem vel eum </p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No, because the very first rule has higher [specificity](http://www.htmldog.com/guides/cssadvanced/specificity/) than the others.

The "last one wins" rule only applies to CSS rules when they have the same specificity.

Answer (score 0):

All is right, your p became yellow, because of css priority. Read this [article](http://www.stoimen.com/blog/2010/03/11/css-priority-the-difference-between-a-my-class-and-my-class/), it helps you.